# Id in IntentHandler class is different

Tags: swift, xcode, widgetkit

**I'm trying to figure out why the id in the IntentHandler class is different than the one from the "fromId" function in the Contact class. I've tried everything but can't find the error.**

[GitHub Repo of the Widget ("Dynamic Intent Widget")](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples)

Contact Class

```
struct Contact: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var dateOfBirth: Date
}

extension Contact {
    static func getAll() -> [Contact] {
        let key = Key.contacts.rawValue
        guard let contacts: [Contact] = UserDefaults.appGroup.getArray(forKey: key) else {
            let contacts: [Contact] = [.friend1, .friend2]
            UserDefaults.appGroup.setArray(contacts, forKey: key)
            return contacts
        }
        return contacts
    }

    static let friend1: Contact = {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -2, to: Date())!
        return Contact(name: "Friend 1", dateOfBirth: date)
    }()

    static let friend2: Contact = {
        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -3, to: Date())!
        return Contact(name: "Friend 2", dateOfBirth: date)
    }()
}

extension Contact {
    static func fromId(_ id: String) -> Contact? {
        getAll().first { $0.id == id }
    }
}
```

UserDefaults:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func setArray<Element>(_ array: [Element], forKey key: String) where Element: Encodable {
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(array)
        set(data, forKey: key)
    }

    func getArray<Element>(forKey key: String) -> [Element]? where Element: Decodable {
        guard let data = data(forKey: key) else { return nil }
        return try? JSONDecoder().decode([Element].self, from: data)
    }
}
```

IntentHandler

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, DynamicPersonSelectionIntentHandling {
    func providePersonOptionsCollection(
        for intent: DynamicPersonSelectionIntent,
        with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Person>?, Error?) -> Void
    ) {
        let persons = Contact.getAll()
            .map { Person(identifier: $0.id, display: $0.name) }
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: persons)
        completion(collection, nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or you are using String and UUID interchangeably? Choose one...

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, could you please explain it to me in more detail. @CloudBalancing